# Serilog's :l specifier is not working for the file sink

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I am trying to provide a template for our old logging schema which looks like this:

```
"{ClassicTimestamp:l}\t{ProductName:l}\t{ProductVersion:l}\t-1\t{LogLevelDigit}\t{LogLevelLetter:l}\t{Message:lj}%R%{ClassicException}\t{ProcessId}\t{ThreadId}{NewLine}"
```

The ":l" is supposed to remove the quotes around the strings. Does that not work with enriched strings? (The first three strings are from my custom enrichers for example)

Why is it not working?